# 2-connected Property of a Graph (Proof Verification)

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

Let $G$ be an $n$-vertex graph with $n\geq 3$. If for every (ordered) triple of vertices, $(x,y,z)$, there exists an $x,z$-path through $y$, then $G$ is $2$-connected.

**Proof:** Assume that for every (ordered) triple of vertices, $(x,y,z)$, there exists an $x,z$-path through $y$. Hence, the order $(y,x,z)$ ensures that there exists a $y,z$-path containing $x$. This implies that there exists an $x,z$-path that does not contain $y$, as paths do not duplicate vertices. **Since $y$ is an arbitrary vertex that is contained in an $x,z$-path, this is true for all vertices $y\in V(G)$ such that  $y\neq x, y\neq z$.**

Thus, by appending the $x,z$-path through $y$ to the $x,z$-path which does not contain $y$ yields a cycle through $x$ and $z$. We conclude that for any $x,z\in V(G)$, there exists a cycle containing $x$ and $z$. Therefore, $G$ is 2-connected.

I'm not sure if I am leaving a gap when I make the statement **'since y is an arbitrary vertex that is contained in an $x,z$-path, this is true for all $y\in V(G):y\neq x, y\neq z$.'**

Comment: For the part in bold: it is true that whenever $y \notin \{ x, z \}$ you have two paths from $x$ to $z$, one containing $y$ and the other not containing $y$. However: 1) there is no compatibility condition, that is these paths may be very different if you change your $y$ a priori. And most importantly 2) joinig two different paths with the same endpoint does not necessarily give you a cycle! You only know that one passes through $y$ and the other doesn't, and if you want to change your $y$ then the paths might change as well, so you cannot say that

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are desiring $P_{yxz}$ to follow start at $y$ and then follow $P_{xyz}$ back to $x$, and then from $x$ the path $P_{yxz}$ doesn't cross $P_{xyz}$ until back at $z$. And this looks tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that you were looking for proof verification and that seems tough [see my comment above]. There is however, an easier way to prove this, and it may be the desired proof:

Suppose $G$ is not 2-connected. Then $G$ has a cut vertex $x$; i.e., there is a vertex $x$ such that $G \setminus \{x\}$ has at least two components. Then let $z \not =x $ be in one component and $y \not =x$ be in another component. Then there is no path $P_{xzy}$ from $x$ to $z$ that contains $y$. [Indeed, if there were such a path $P_{yxz}$ then there are paths $P_{xy}$ and $P_{yz}$ from $x$ to $y$, and $y$ to $z$, that intersect precisely at $y$. But as $x$ is a cut vertex and $y$ and $z$ are in different components of $G \setminus \{x\}$ it follws that $P_{yz}$ has to also contain $x \in P_{xy}$ as well.]

Thus, from the  above, we note: if $G$ is not 2-connected, then there is an ordered triple $(x,y,z)$ such that $G$ has no path from $x$ to $z$ containing $y$. The result follows.

---

You could also assume that $G$ has at least 4 vertices and, this time writing as $x'$ the cut vertex, have $x$, $y$, and $z$ be such that $x$ and $y$ are in different components of $G \setminus \{x'\}$, and then $y$ and $z$ in different components of  $G \setminus \{x'\}$ [it doesn't matter if $x$ and $z$ are in the same component of $G \setminus \{x'\}$.]

Comment: Approaching this problem by contraposition does seem to more appropriate. Thanks for that